# Visual Studio WPF How to make text ina a label instantly change when writing something in a TextBox

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, textbox, label

So i have a Textbox and a Label.
if I write something in the Textbox I would like the Label to show instaltly the text that I am currently writing in the Textbox.

Comment: Bind a common property to both controls and keep two way binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as this if you don't want to store the data in code behind or something.

Just bind the **Content** property of the label to the **Text** property of the text box like this : `Content="{Binding ElementName=TextBox1, Path=Text}"`

Check sample code below!

```
<Window x:Class="TestApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="203,109,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=TextBox1, Path=Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="203,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If you want to save the data then bind both Content and Text property to a single **Property** and enable **TwoWay** binding.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflowWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <Label Margin="15" x:Name="lbl"></Label>
    <TextBox Width="220" Height="40" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" x:Name="txtBox" 
             Text="{Binding ElementName=lbl, Path=Content, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```